# CSS IE displaying double list-style icons

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-lists

I'm having a problem with Internet Explorer(all versions) displaying 2 types of list-style icons in a UL. This is only happening in IE in Firefox,Chrome and Safari it is only displaying the list-style specified whether it is a normal string of text or if it's a hyperlink. Here is what the html and CSS look like:

[image: Here are the screenshots]

```
#altslider dd {
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left: 0;
    display: list-item;
    list-style:url(../images/altbullet.png);
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #333;
}

#altslider dd a {
    margin-top: 16px;
    display: list-item;
    list-style:url(../images/altlinkbullet.png);
    color: #000068;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<dl>
    <dd><a href="javascript:submitComment()" class="mynext">创建提供思科产品、服务和解决方案的品牌网络商店</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="javascript:submitComment()" class="bullet2">搜索并投标待完成 IT 项目</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="javascript:submitComment()" class="bullet3">管理账户并追踪交易</a></dd>
</dl>

<dl>
    <dd>建立一个思科产品、服务和解决方案的产品组合</dd>
    <dd>为产品、服务和解决方案定价</dd>
    <dd>管理公司简档和产品营销细节</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Please provide a better code snippet.

Comment: I see 2 list-style images.  One for an `a` tag and one for a `dd` tag.  Are these the two images that IE is displaying?

Comment: Yes exactly. However in the other browsers it only displays the a tag style where as in IE it's displaying both the dd tag and the a style.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the `list-style` declaration for the `a` tag styling?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid doing that because I need that different list-style to indicate links. I was given a Flash presentation and needed to create a mobile friendly version that matches the same style.

Comment: I came up with a solution. Rather than apply the CSS to all of the dd tags I created a class of .altbullet for normal text strings and a separate class called .altbullet link for the slides with links. I applied the classes to the appropriate DL tags and now everything is working correctly in all browsers. Thanks guys for the suggestions. I thought I'd post back with the solution in the odd event someone has a similar problem as I faced.